# How to catch OnclickEvent event when controls are added dynamically?

Tags: asp.net

i am trying to add imgbutton dynamically  i works but i want when a user click on one of then he will be send to the image page which in case is in img.Id so now what to do . how to add only one event to my code and get to work it fro n no. of controls?

```
          {  ImageButton img = new ImageButton();
            img.ID = "projectimg" + i.ToString();
            img.ImageUrl = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
            img.Height = 120;
            img.Width = 120;
            img.ToolTip = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
            img.OnClientClick += new System.EventHandler(this.Onclick_evn);
            pnlgallery.Controls.Add(img);
```

}

```
        private void Onclick_evn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;
    string link = btn.ImageUrl;
    Image8.ImageUrl = link;
    Image8.Height = 500;
    Image8.Width = 500;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its `OnClick` and not <strike>`OnClientClick`</strike>

```
img.OnClick += new System.EventHandler(this.Onclick_evn);
```

And the EventHandler has a slightly different signature.

```
private void Onclick_evn(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;
    string link = btn.ImageUrl;
    Image8.ImageUrl = link;
    Image8.Height = 500;
    Image8.Width = 500;
}
```